# Helm private values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I could not find anything by just googling, does Helm support private values?

So I have my chart and my `values.yaml`

```
privateProp: hello

publicProp: world
```

I have some values that I want to exposed to the end user of my chart and others that I do not want, however those "private" values are being used in many places.

For example: `publicProps` is overridable by the user of the chart, but I would like to block access to `privateProp`, however it is reused in many places:

```
containers:
  name: {{.Values.privateProp}}
```

```
nodeSelector:
  name: {{.Values.privateProp}}
```

I saw there is `{{$privateProp := "hello"}}`, but it is not clear how I can access it elsewhere in my files

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i'd rather call that `const` than `private`? whom exactly do you want to "block"?

Comment: I just want to use it as an internal value

Comment: what does `internal` mean here?

Comment: that is not accessible from `values.yaml`

Comment: what is the bad effect if can be accessed from `values.yaml`?

Comment: i never heard `values.yaml` breaks chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution to my problem.

You can create a file called `_variables.tpl`, the name does not matter

and then declare a variable:

```
{{- define "privateProp" -}}
{{- print "hello" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

and then you can use it wherever you want in your chart by doing this:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.dashboard.containers.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ include "privateProp" . }} # <== This
```

Comment: There is nothing private about this. A wrapper chart can override that template block if it wants. It's just obfuscated. Don't do this.

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: All I want is to not expose that parameter, and at the same time, make it re-usable across my chart's files

Comment: Why do you not want them "exposed"? I think you misunderstand how Helm works. My suggestion would be to use a normal value like all other charts.

Comment: @coderanger yep, you were right, I have indeed reverted my changes